# Why is python so slow on Raring?

Tags: 13.04, python, java

In order to run a few benchmarks on my newly installed 13.04, I wrote the below fibonacci script in python. It basically accepts a number and starts crunching fibonacci numbers that many times:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from time import time

def fibo(n):
    a,b,i=0,1,0
    while i<n:
        #print b
        a,b = b,b+a
        i+=1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s=time()
    fibo(1000000)
    print round((time()-s)*1000,0),"ms"
```

However, when the fibo() function is called with 1 million as parameter, the python seems to hang. While, this similar code in java runs instantly:

```
class fibonacci
{
    private static void fibo(int n)
    {
        int a=0,b=1,i=0;
        while( i<n)
        {
            //print b
            int t=a;
            a=b;
            b=b+t;
            i++;
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float s=System.currentTimeMillis();
        fibo(1000000);
        System.out.println( (System.currentTimeMillis()-s) + "ms");
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this? Is python inherently that slow or is something wrong with my raring installation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Java code, I notice you are using `int` for the Fibonacci numbers.
On the other hand, Python is using *arbitrary precision*.

Also notice that the Fibonacci numbers won't fit in an `int` variable for `n > 46`!
So the Java code isn't even calculating Fibonacci numbers for `n > 46`.

You should change the `int` for some bigger data type (an arbitrary precision one, maybe), before you make the comparison.

Conclusion, Java runs this much faster because it is calculating with ints (a fixed size data type), while Python is using more and more RAM to accumulate for the ever increasing numbers (which eventually cease to fit in a 32-bit integer).

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import time

def int32(x):
    x &= 0xffffffff
    if x > 0x7fffffff:
        return - ( ~(x - 1) & 0xffffffff )
    else:
        return x

def fibo(n):
    a,b,i=0,1,0
    while i<n:
        t = a
        a = b
        b = int32(b + t)
        i+=1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s=time()
    fibo(1000000)
    print round((time()-s)*1000,0),"ms"
```

to see approximately how much time would it take if Python used ints.

Comment: I think you are right. When I added the line             "System.out.println(a);" at the end of the loop in my java code, it printed -4249520595888827205 which is obviously a wrong value. But then it should have shouted by throwing an exception, rather than mutely processing an incompatible variable.

Comment: In java once the int type overflows its bounds (-2,147,483,648 – 2,147,483,647) it starts printing out seemingly random numbers. Java doesn't notify you about this in form of an exception.

Answer (score 2):

A little excerpt from http://www.python.org/doc/essays/comparisons.html should answer your question.
The short answer is in the first sentence ;)

> "Python programs are generally expected to run slower than Java
>   programs, but they also take much less time to develop. Python
>   programs are typically 3-5 times shorter than equivalent Java
>   programs. This difference can be attributed to Python's built-in
>   high-level data types and its dynamic typing. For example, a Python
>   programmer wastes no time declaring the types of arguments or
>   variables, and Python's powerful polymorphic list and dictionary
>   types, for which rich syntactic support is built straight into the
>   language, find a use in almost every Python program. Because of the
>   run-time typing, Python's run time must work harder than Java's. For
>   example, when evaluating the expression a+b, it must first inspect the
>   objects a and b to find out their type, which is not known at compile
>   time. It then invokes the appropriate addition operation, which may be
>   an overloaded user-defined method. Java, on the other hand, can
>   perform an efficient integer or floating point addition, but requires
>   variable declarations for a and b, and does not allow overloading of
>   the + operator for instances of user-defined classes.
>
> For these reasons, Python is much better suited as a "glue" language,
>   while Java is better characterized as a low-level implementation
>   language. In fact, the two together make an excellent combination.
>   Components can be developed in Java and combined to form applications
>   in Python; Python can also be used to prototype components until their
>   design can be "hardened" in a Java implementation. To support this
>   type of development, a Python implementation written in Java is under
>   development, which allows calling Python code from Java and vice
>   versa. In this implementation, Python source code is translated to
>   Java bytecode (with help from a run-time library to support Python's
>   dynamic semantics)."

Comment: "...are slower than Java programs" is a very relative statement. Agreed that python programs may run 3-5 times, or even 10 times slower than java programs, but the above scenario is totally different. The python script hangs on for ages, while the java one completes in a few milliseconds for the same functionality!! I don't think such a huge difference is only attributable to the compiler/interpreter paradigm. I suspect something else is missing here - either I've missed something in the code or raring has some issues related to python.

Comment: Have you tried this same script in other platforms (besides Ubuntu 13.04)??